# Composite typeclasses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Is there any practical difference between

```hs
class (From a b, To a b) => IsomorphismFromTo a b 
instance (From a b, To a b) => IsomorphismFromTo a b
```

and

```hs
type IsomorphismFromTo a b = (From a b, To a b)
```

where no instance of `IsomorphismFromTo a b` is provided apart from the trivial one,
apart from the ability to quantify

```hs
--type IsomorphismFromTo a b = (From a b, To a b) -- fails
class (From a, To a) => IsomorphismFromTo a b  -- works


type IsomorphismFromTo1 f g = forall x. IsomorphismFromTo (f x) (g x) 
-- "You can't specify an instance for a tuple constraint" with the constraint synonym
```

Comment: The former says that two types *can* have an `IsomorphismFromTo a b` if `From a b` and `To a b` are satisfied. Whereas the `type IsomorphismFromTo` is equivalent to `From a b` and `To a b`.

Comment: yes, I mean with no instances of `IsomorphismFromTo a b` provided. I will update

Comment: The difference between the constraint synonym and `type` is that the former can be partially applied. When making synonyms of constraints I exclusively use constraint synonyms. However modeling isomorphisms with type classes is not going to end well, you won't even be able to encode identity and composition because of overlap. If you are willing to go through the effort, you should can use [ghc plugins](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-tcplugin-api) to have precise control over elaboration.

Comment: We can call `f :: forall c . c T U => ...` as `f @IsomorphismFromTo` only if it's a class and not a synonym. This extends to other similar cases where a type variable `c` has to be instantiated with your class.

Comment: good points ... thank you. some article from Ryan Scott seem to dig into nearby subject https://ryanglscott.github.io/2019/11/30/four-ways-to-partially-apply-constraint-tuples/

Comment: I forget to mention, having a new TC requires `UndecidableInstances` which means many programs can be accepted with no proof when there is a loop between instances